# Chain rule in higher derivatives and multiple dimensions.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

Alright, rather simple problem that I just don't think I'm wrapping my head around properly. I'm given that $v = v(u)\ and\ u = u(r,t).$ The first derivatives in either dimension are simple enough, with $\partial{v}/\partial{t} = \partial{v}/\partial{u}*\partial{u}/\partial{t}$ and $\partial{v}/\partial{r} = \partial{v}/\partial{u}*\partial{u}/\partial{r}.$ However, I'm stuck on what the second derivatives are. Do I just square both of those to get $\partial^2{v}/\partial{t}^2 = \partial^2{v}/\partial{u}^2*\partial^2{u}/\partial^2{t}$ and $\partial^2{v}/\partial{r}^2 = \partial^2{v}/\partial{u}^2*\partial^2{u}/\partial^2{r}$ (or something similar)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not how it works. You have to apply the chain rule again.
$$
\frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial t^2}=\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left(\frac{\partial v}{\partial t}\right)=\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left(\frac{dv}{du}\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}\right)=\frac{d^2v}{du^2}\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}\right)^2+\frac{dv}{du}\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2}
$$
and similarly for $\frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial r^2}$.